# onSaved of textformfield not being called but the validator is

Tags: android, forms, firebase, flutter, dart

When I run my program to submit this form, the validator runs and returns with correct error checking however I can not come up with a  method to get the onSaved method of the TextFormFields to work. I do not however receive any errors when running the code and the dropdown buttons work and upload to firebase properly. I currently have name set to a print to the logcat for debugging, but it never gets called.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:connectuproject/authentication.dart';

class player_reg extends StatefulWidget {
  player_reg(this.auth);

  final BaseAuth auth;

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => new PlayerRegState();
}

class PlayerRegState extends State<player_reg> {
  final _formKey = new GlobalKey<FormState>();


  String _name = "";
  String _age = "";
  String _grad = "";
  String _highschool = "";
  String _city = "";
  String _state = "";

  String _heightFeet = "";
  String _heightInch = "";
  String _weight = "";
  String _hand = "Right";

  String _number = "";
  String _email = "";
  String _errorMessage = "";

  String _position = "Attack";
  String _club = "";

  bool _isLoading = false;



  bool validateAndSave() {
    if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
      _formKey.currentState.save();
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }

  void validateAndSubmit() async {
    setState(() {
      _errorMessage = "";
      _isLoading = true;
    });
    print("Auth: " + widget.auth.getUserId());

    if (validateAndSave()) {
      try {
        String _uid = widget.auth.getUserId();
        print("_uid: " + _uid + " Name: " + _name);
        final databaseReference = Firestore.instance;
        await databaseReference.collection("users").document(_uid).setData({
          'name': _name,
          'age': _age,
          'grade': _grad,
          'highschool': _highschool,
          'state': _state,
          'city': _city,
          'heightFeet': _heightFeet,
          'heightInch': _heightInch,
          'weight': _weight,
          'hand': _hand,
          'position': _position,
          'club': _club,
        });
      }
      catch(e){
        print(e.message);
      }
    }
    setState(() {
      _isLoading = false;
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    _errorMessage = "";
    _isLoading = false;
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(
          title: new Text('Flutter login demo'),
        ),
        body: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            _showForm(),
            _showCircularProgress(),
          ],
        ));
  }

  Widget _showCircularProgress() {
    if (_isLoading) {
      return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
    }
    return Container(
      height: 0.0,
      width: 0.0,
    );
  }

  Widget _showForm() {
    return new Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
        child: new Form(
          key: _formKey,
          child: new ListView(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            children: <Widget>[
              showInstruct(),
              showPerson(),
              showNameInput(),
              showAgeInput(),
              showGradInput(),
              showHighschoolInput(),
              showStateInput(),
              showCityInput(),
              showPhysical(),
              showHeightFeetInput(),
              showHeightInchesInput(),
              showWeightInput(),
              showHandiness(),
              showHandinessInput(),
              showContact(),
              showNumberInput(),
              showEmailInput(),
              showLacrosse(),
              showPosition(),
              showPositionInput(),
              showClubInput(),
              showSubmitButton(),
            ],
          ),
        ),
    );
  }

  Widget showInstruct() {
    return new Text(
      "Please complete the following ",
      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
      style: TextStyle(
        color: Colors.black,
        fontFamily: 'Raleway',
        fontSize: 30.0,
        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget showPerson() {
    return new Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0.0, 50.0, 0.0, 0.0),
        child: new Text(
          "Personal info: ",
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.black,
            fontFamily: 'Raleway',
            fontSize: 30.0,
          ),
        ));
  }

  Widget showNameInput() {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0.0, 25.0, 0.0, 0.0),
      child: new TextFormField(
        maxLines: 1,
        autofocus: false,
        decoration: new InputDecoration(
          hintText: 'Name',
        ),
        validator: (value) => value.isEmpty ? 'Name can\'t be empty' : null,
        onSaved: (String value) => print("saving the name value of " + value),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget showAgeInput() {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0.0, 25.0, 0.0, 0.0),
      child: new TextFormField(
        maxLines: 1,
        maxLength: 2,
        autofocus: false,
        keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
        decoration: new InputDecoration(
          hintText: 'Age',
        ),
        validator: (value) => value.isEmpty ? 'Age can\'t be empty' : null,
        onSaved: (String value) => _age = value.trim(),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget showGradInput() {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0.0, 25.0, 0.0, 0.0),
      child: new TextFormField(
        maxLines: 1,
        maxLength: 4,
        autofocus: false,
        keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
        decoration: new InputDecoration(
          hintText: 'Graduation year',
        ),
        validator: (value) =>
            value.isEmpty ? 'Graduation year can\'t be empty' : null,
        onSaved: (String value) => _grad = value.trim(),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget showHighschoolInput() {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0.0, 25.0, 0.0, 0.0),
      child: new TextFormField(
        maxLines: 1,
        autofocus: false,
        decoration: new InputDecoration(
          hintText: 'Highschool',
        ),
        validator: (value) =>
            value.isEmpty ? 'Highschool can\'t be empty' : null,
        onSaved: (String value) => _highschool = value.trim(),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget showStateInput() {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0.0, 25.0, 0.0, 0.0),
      child: new TextFormField(
        maxLines: 1,
        autofocus: false,
        decoration: new InputDecoration(
          hintText: 'State',
        ),
        validator: (value) => value.isEmpty ? 'State can\'t be empty' : null,
        onSaved: (String value) => _state = value.trim(),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget showCityInput() {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0.0, 25.0, 0.0, 50.0),
      child: new TextFormField(
        maxLines: 1,
        autofocus: false,
        decoration: new InputDecoration(
          hintText: 'City',
        ),
        validator: (value) => value.isEmpty ? 'State can\'t be empty' : null,
        onSaved: (String value) => _city = value.trim(),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget showPhysical() {
    return new Text(
      "Physical info: ",
      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
      style: TextStyle(
        color: Colors.black,
        fontFamily: 'Raleway',
        fontSize: 30.0,
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget showHeightFeetInput() {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0.0, 25.0, 0.0, 0.0),
      child: new TextFormField(
        maxLines: 1,
        maxLength: 1,
        autofocus: false,
        keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
        decoration: new InputDecoration(
          hintText: 'Height(feet)',
        ),
        validator: (value) => value.isEmpty ? 'Height can\'t be empty' : null,
        onSaved: (String value) => _heightFeet = value.trim(),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget showHeightInchesInput() {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0.0, 25.0, 0.0, 0.0),
      child: new TextFormField(
        maxLines: 1,
        maxLength: 2,
        autofocus: false,
        keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
        decoration: new InputDecoration(
          hintText: 'Height(inches)',
        ),
        validator: (value) => value.isEmpty ? 'Height can\'t be empty' : null,
        onSaved: (String value) => _heightInch = value.trim(),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget showWeightInput() {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0.0, 25.0, 0.0, 0.0),
      child: new TextFormField(
        maxLines: 1,
        maxLength: 3,
        autofocus: false,
        keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
        decoration: new InputDecoration(
          hintText: 'weight(lbs)',
        ),
        validator: (value) => value.isEmpty ? 'Weight can\'t be empty' : null,
        onSaved: (String value) => _weight = value.trim(),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget showHandiness() {
    return new Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0.0, 25.0, 0.0, 0.0),
      child: Text(
        "Handiness:",
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget showHandinessInput() {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0),
      child: Container(
          width: double.infinity,
          child: new DropdownButton<String>(
            isExpanded: true,
            value: _hand,
            elevation: 16,
            underline: Container(
              height: 2,
            ),
            onChanged: (String newValue) {
              setState(() {
                _hand = newValue;
              });
            },
            items: <String>['Right','Left']
                .map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
              return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                value: value,
                child: Text(value),
              );
            }).toList(),
          )),
    );
  }

  Widget showContact() {
    return new Text(
      "Contact info: ",
      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
      style: TextStyle(
        color: Colors.black,
        fontFamily: 'Raleway',
        fontSize: 30.0,
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget showNumberInput() {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0.0, 25.0, 0.0, 0.0),
      child: new TextFormField(
        maxLines: 1,
        autofocus: false,
        keyboardType: TextInputType.phone,
        decoration: new InputDecoration(
          hintText: 'Phone Number',
        ),
        validator: (value) => value.isEmpty ? 'Number can\'t be empty' : null,
        onSaved: (String value) => _number = value.trim(),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget showEmailInput() {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0.0, 25.0, 0.0, 50.0),
      child: new TextFormField(
        maxLines: 1,
        autofocus: false,
        keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
        decoration: new InputDecoration(
          hintText: 'Email',
        ),
        validator: (value) => value.isEmpty ? 'Not a valid Email' : null,
        onSaved: (String value) => _email = value.trim(),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget showLacrosse() {
    return new Text(
      "Lacrosse info: ",
      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
      style: TextStyle(
        color: Colors.black,
        fontFamily: 'Raleway',
        fontSize: 30.0,
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget showPosition() {
    return new Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0.0, 25.0, 0.0, 0.0),
        child: Text(
          "Position:",
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
        ));
  }

  Widget showPositionInput() {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0),
      child: Container(
          width: double.infinity,
          child: new DropdownButton<String>(
            isExpanded: true,
            value: _position,
            elevation: 16,
            underline: Container(
              height: 2,
            ),
            onChanged: (String newValue) {
              setState(() {
                _position = newValue;
              });
            },
            items: <String>[
              'Attack',
              'Defense',
              'Face-off',
              'Goalie',
              'Long Stick Midfield',
              'Midfield'
            ].map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
              return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                value: value,
                child: Text(value),
              );
            }).toList(),
          )),
    );
  }

  Widget showClubInput() {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0.0, 25.0, 0.0, 50.0),
      child: new TextFormField(
        maxLines: 1,
        autofocus: false,
        decoration: new InputDecoration(
          hintText: 'Club Team',
        ),
        onSaved: (String value) => _club = value.trim(),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget showSubmitButton() {
    return new Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0.0, 45.0, 0.0, 25.0),
        child: SizedBox(
          height: 40.0,
          child: new RaisedButton(
            elevation: 5.0,
            shape: new RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(30.0)),
            color: Colors.blue,
            child: new Text("Submit"),
            onPressed: validateAndSubmit,
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

enter code here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a few days of hard effort I realized the form fields were clearing when I scrolled down the screen. The solution was to wrap the entire field in a SingleChildScrollView and replace my list view with a column.